# How to check if a group is similar to another, in two different classifications

Tags: classification, frequency, fishers-exact-test

Suppose I have two different classification, e.g.

```
     C    R
s1  c1   r2
s2  c1   r2
s3  c3   r2
...
```

Where sn are the classified samples and the columns of the matrix represent the different classifications (one called `R` - reference, the other `C` - clustering).

I want to check if, for example, c1 samples are significantly classified (read: the most part) as r2. If so, I say that r2 samples are *enriched* in c1 (I do not know if it's the correct term).

To do so I thought about checking if a r-class is enriched in an c-class. I thought about checking if r-class is more present in c-class samples with respect to all the other r-classes combined. I checked significance using fisher exact test on samples count.

My contigency table is:

```
a = samples in ci AND in rj
b = samples in ci AND NOT in rj
c = samples not in ci AND in rj
d = samples not in ci AND NOT in rj

       rj   ~rj
 ci     a     b
~ci     c     d
```

Doing so, I expect to find if the distribution of samples is significantly different. If so, and if a and d are larger than b and c (read: samples count of rj is maximized in ci and samples count of the other rj-classes is maximized in the other ci-classes), I think I can assume that I can say rj is enriched in ci.

Does this make sense?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it makes sense